# Getting QueryBuilder as NULL in WCM.IO junit test framework for AEM code base

Tags: junit, aem

We are getting QueryBuilder as NULL in WCM.IO junit implementation

```
QueryBuilder querybuilder = getSlingScriptHelper().getService(QueryBuilder.class);
Query query = querybuilder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(queryMap), session);
```

Above "querybuilder" is coming as NULL when we are are writting Junit Test class by wcm.io implementation.

We used wcm.io methods for registering QueryBuilder service in wcm.io junit class. Methods which we used:

```
context.registerService(QueryBuilder.class, new QueryBuilderImpl()); 
context.registerInjectActivateService(new QueryBuilderImpl());
```

Comment: Which version of AEM you are using?

Comment: Ekta we are using AEM6.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to mock QueryBuilder using below approach :

```
QueryBuilder qb= mock(QueryBuilder.class);
TestClass obj = new TestClass(){
    @Override
    public SlingScriptHelper getSlingScriptHelper() {
        return slingScriptHelper;
    };
};
```

And then to use it :

```
 when(carouselComponent.getSlingScriptHelper().getService(QueryBuilder.class)).thenReturn(qb);
```

Comment: Is this still the way to go in 2018?